# postgreSQL server not loading

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to install postgreSQL(11) server on my local machine.I have downloaded PgAdmin 4(Mac) from the official website and installed it.

When I open the pgadmin the server is opening on **random ports like 55957,55062** etc, not on 5432.

I have edited my "PostgreSQL.conf" and changed the **listen address=*** and **port =5432** ,but I could not able to restart the service.
When I type **"sudo service postgreSQL restart"** it was showing **"Sudo : Service command not found"**
Also "Sudo command not found".

I don't have much experience in installing postgreSQL ,Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong and let me know how I can add the server in postgres.

Note: I have opened pgadmin - select add new server - localhost as server name and User and DB as postgres.But when I put 5432 as port it was giving the common error "Whether TCP/ip accepting on 5432" and when I put the port where the pgadmin server is currently running (127.0.0.1:55097) it was getting timed out exception.

Comment: If you are using postgres for research/educational purposes, you may try running it inside docker container: just install docker and then follow the [official postgres instruction](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). It would start postgres on `localhost:5432` and you will definitely be able to connect to it from pgadmin

Comment: You have to first check if the server is running or not.
Try this from location  /Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin
**./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data/  status**

if it is not running, Start it by using the below command:
**./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data/  start**

Comment: pgAdmin and PostgreSQL are different things.  It would be bad if pgAdmin were trying to listen on the same port number as PostgreSQL itself was.

Comment: @RandomGuy Not for educational purpose.But for a testing environment .